# I need help resolving "unexpected token" error when setting up invocable variables in a test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, invocable-method, invocablevariable

I have an invocable method with varables. I am stuck how to set these in a test class, below is the progress I've made. I am getting an errror "Unexpected token '='" on the last couple lines of the test class when trying to setup the variables. Any help is appreciated!

Class:

```
global class UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag implements queueable {
    
    InvocableVariables[] request;
    public UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag(InvocableVariables[] request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
    //Invocable method called from flow
    @InvocableMethod    
    public static void UpdateIntegrationFlag(List <InvocableVariables> request){
        System.enqueueJob(new UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag(request));
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        
        //invocable variables
        List<Project_Order__c> recordIDs = request[0].recordIDs;
        String actionToPerform = request[0].actionToPerform;

       //Business logic here...
    }    
    global class InvocableVariables{
     
        //List of record IDs to process
        @InvocableVariable public List <Project_Order__c> recordIDs;
        @InvocableVariable public String actionToPerform;

        
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@istest
public class UpdProjReqIntFlag_Test {
   
    UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag.InvocableVariables variables1 = new UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag.InvocableVariables();
    List <Project_Order__c> projectRequestIDs = [Select Id FROM Project_Order__c limit 10];
    
    variables1.recordIDs = projectRequestIDs;
    variables1.actionToPerform = 'Pending';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test class doesn't contain a test method. That is, your test code is "loose" in the body of the class, which isn't valid in Apex. Add a test method to allow this code to compile and execute:

```
@istest
public class UpdProjReqIntFlag_Test {

    @isTest
    public static void runTest() {
        UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag.InvocableVariables variables1 = new UpdateProjectRequestIntegrationFlag.InvocableVariables();
        List <Project_Order__c> projectRequestIDs = [Select Id FROM Project_Order__c limit 10];
    
        variables1.recordIDs = projectRequestIDs;
        variables1.actionToPerform = 'Pending';

        // Execute functionality.

        // Assert the results.
    }
}
```